# social_django, redirect_uri is incorrect, vk backend

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth, django-socialauth

After migration from python-social-auth to split social according to this [file](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/blob/master/MIGRATING_TO_SOCIAL.md) I get 401 error (`DEBUG=False`) when somebody want to sign in using VK backend.

> 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://oauth.vk.com/access_token
>
> Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/requests/models.py in raise_for_status, line 844

What I have tried to far:

1. I have tried to reset VK app keys and change them in settings.
2. Also I have checked the redirect URI's in VK app and they are the same as in the request.

I think the problem is not with VK app setup but most probably in missing settings inside of split social Django app. Any ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved after

1. I had two redirect URI's in my VK app settings. (one with "www", another without) I have removed one.
2. I added again "'social.apps.django_app.default' into the settings.py